# What are "modal-verbs"?

Tags: modal-verbs

Are they the same as the "verbs-of-being" I was <s>forced to painstakingly memorize</s>taught in Middle School? I.e.

- Be
- Am
- Is
- Are
- Was
- Were
- Being
- Been
- Have
- Has
- Had
- Shall
- Will
- May
- Can
- Might
- Could
- Should
- Would

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The modal verbs are a subset of the "verbs of being", which are properly called *auxiliary verbs*. The classical modal verbs are:

- shall
- should
- will
- would
- may
- might
- must
- can
- could

Modal verbs are peculiar in that they have no infinitive form (you can't say *to shall*) and cannot be combined with other modal verbs in Standard English (you can't say *I will might go*).

By way of contrast, the other auxiliary verbs are formed from *be*, *have*, and *do*, and they don't have these properties. You can say *to be*, and you can combine a non-modal auxiliary with a modal: *I **should have** bought those shoes.*

For more detailed discussion, [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_auxiliary_verb).

Comment: I will might have learned something from your answer! ;-)

Comment: +1 -- can you stick this info in the [Modal-Verbs tag-wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/modal-verbs/info) so that future seers of that tag don't get confused? Oh, and have a checkmark thingy :P

Comment: "will" has an infinitive form (i.e. to will something to occur/"There will be water if God wills it") but obviously that's different than the typical usage to say "that will occur in the future" (EDIT: For that matter so does "can", i.e. "one cans fish to keep it from spoiling", or "to can fish is to prevent it from spoiling")

Comment: @Billy, I would argue that *to will* and *to can* are different words from the modals *will* and *can*, though they are homophones.  In the case of *will* there is an etymological connection between the full verb and the modal verb, but I'm pretty sure that there is no connection at all between the different senses of *can*.

Comment: I agree. Was just being nit-picky :)

Comment: Well actually the infinitive form of *can* is normally given as *to be able* and this is not that different to the infinitive form of *is* being *to be*. Other verbs that could be added to the list include *ought to* (also doesn't have a cognate infinitive), *has to*, *is supposed to*. What distinguishes your list is that the **following** infinitive has the *to* omitted. But this is about form not function.  They deal with things that are irreal possibilities in some sense.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "classic" and not "classical?"